How to filter out a dataframe based on another dataframe
My dataframe loads from a csv file that looks like this
RepID   Account    Rank
123     Abcd       1
345     Zyxw       2
567     Hijk       3
...
...
837    Kjsj        8

and I have another csv that has only one column
RepID
345
488

I load the first csv in a dataframe df and the other csv in dataframe dE
I want to have a new datafrmae dX that is all records from df that RepID does not exist in dE
and dY all the records that RepID exist in dE
how to do that?

A possible solution, which uses boolean indexing and isin:
df[df['RepID'].isin(dE['RepID'])] # dY

df[~df['RepID'].isin(dE['RepID'])] # dX

Output:
# dY
   RepID Account  Rank
1    345    Zyxw     2

# dX
   RepID Account  Rank
0    123    Abcd     1
2    567    Hijk     3
3    837    Kjsj     8


Here’s an example without isin and should be more extendable based on what your doing:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'RepID': [123, 345, 567, 837],
    'Account': ['Abcd', 'Zyxw', 'Hijk', 'Kjsj'],
    'Rank': [1, 2, 3, 8]
})

dE = pd.DataFrame({'RepID': [345, 488]})

merged = df.merge(dE, on='RepID', how='outer', indicator=True)

df_x = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns='_merge')
df_y = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'both'].drop(columns='_merge')

print(df_x)
print(df_y)

   RepID Account  Rank
0    123    Abcd     1
2    567    Hijk     3
3    837    Kjsj     8


   RepID Account  Rank
1    345    Zyxw     2

